# Reading-File Algorithm keeps repeating data of previous lines

Tags: c, algorithm, file

I am trying to write an algorithm able to read through a file searching a specific string, which in my case is called 'label'.
The concept is simple: Read each line until `EOF` and for each line process the content searching for a specific sequence of characters.

The function:

```
char *fsearch(int fd, char *label){
    char c, buffer[500];
    int len, end, k;

    if((fd = open("C:\\Password-Manager\\pssw.txt", O_RDONLY, 0)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to locate file.");
        return NULL;
    }
    for(len = 0; read(fd, &c, 1) == 1;){
        if(c == '\n')
            len++;
    }
    printf("[DEBUG]: File-Length -> %d\n", len);

    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    end = k = 0;
    while(len > 0){
        while(read(fd, &c, 1) == 1){
            if(c == '\n')
                break;
            buffer[k++] = c;
        }
        printf("[DEBUG]: %s\n", buffer);
        len--;
    }
}
```

The function is not completed yet, next step will be parsing the content, but the problem happens right here. With a `printf()` are shown on screen the line that have been save and which will be look up late, here is the result:

```
C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Not_Compressed_Folder\Password Managment System\1.0h>init -sh
[DEBUG]: File-Length -> 3
[DEBUG]: label0 string0
[DEBUG]: label0 string0label1   string1ª↕
[DEBUG]: label0 string0label1   string1label2   string2
```

Why is each time starting over? I supposed was something about the cursor, that jump back to the beginning each time the first while starts over. I still don't know how to fix it.
Any kind of help will be gladly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What did you expect the result to be considering you are adding to the end of `buffer` every time and printing the string at `buffer` ever time. Did you want to store only the last line in buffer? If so you need to set `k=0` before the start of the inner `while` loop.

Comment: Are you forced to use `file descriptor` instead of `FILE pointer`?

Answer (score 0):

It's just because you never delete the content of the buffer, and you keep incrementing k.
So one way to fix this is to put '\0' when you finish reading a line and then you set k back to 0:

```
while(len > 0){
    while(read(fd, &c, 1) == 1){
        if(c == '\n')
            buffer[k] = '\0';
            break;
        buffer[k++] = c;
    }
    printf("[DEBUG]: %s\n", buffer);
    k = 0;
    len--;
}
```

I haven't tried this since I don't have the full code, let me know if it doesn't work.